# Hacer NOT de un numero binario de 8 bits

Tags: java

Quiero que un usuario introduzca un numero binario de 8 bits, el programa compruebe que todos los números están correctos. Si no lo están volver a pedir introducción de números hasta que  los 8 bits sean o 0  o 1.
Tengo todo perfectamente pero a la hora de hacer la negación (convertir todos los 1 en 0 y viceversa), falla, le he estado dando vueltas y no logro que funcione, hay que usar bucles para hacer el cambio

Gracias de antemano

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Not {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Escriba un numero en binario de 8 bits: ");
        String num = entrada.nextLine();

        //Verificar que el numero es de 8 bits y todos los numeros son 0 y 1
        while (num.length() != 8) {
            System.out.print("El numero introducido no tiene 8 bits, vuelva a introducir el valor: ");
            num = entrada.nextLine();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
            char caracter = num.charAt(i);
            if (caracter != '0' && caracter != '1') {
                System.out.println("Error de valor en la posicion " + (i + 1));
                System.out.print("Vuelve a escribir los 8 bits: ");
                num = entrada.nextLine();
            }
        }

        String cambiado = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
            char cambio = num.charAt(i);
            if (cambio == '1') {
                cambio = 1;
                cambiado += cambio;
            } else {
                cambio = 0;
                cambiado += cambio;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("NOT(" + num + ") = " + cambiado);
    }
}
```

Comment: Es que no estás cambiando nada. Si es igual a 1, le pones un 1, y sino le pones un cero que ya es cero... El for donde compruebas si son todo 0 o 1 tampoco está bien. Si en el caracter 3, por ejemplo no hay un 1 o 0, pides la cadena entera, pero la i del for vale 3, así que continuas comprobando la nueva cadena, pero desde la posición 4 en adelante. Las primeras ya no...

Comment: Tal vez la respuesta que publiqué te complemente la respuesta de hacer el **NOT** a un número binario, pues se usa el **operador bitwise NOT**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad son 2 pasos:

Paso 1: Validar que el número ingresado tenga 8 dígitos y que contenga 1 y 0

Paso 2: Recorrer cada dígito del número ingresado y cambiar el 0 por el 1 y viceversa y esto concatenar a otra variable inicializado como vacío. El problema en tu código es que estas declarando la variable `cambio` como char y luego asignas un valor entero, tampoco estas cambiando el 0 por el 1 y viceversa.

Una de las formas de escribir el código sería:

```
public class Not {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Escriba un numero en binario de 8 bits: ");
        String num = entrada.nextLine();
        String numeroNot="";
        
        //Verificar que el numero es de 8 bits y todos los numeros son 0 y 1
        while(!verificarBinario(num)){
            System.out.print("Escriba un numero en binario de 8 bits: ");
            num = entrada.nextLine();
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
            char caracter = num.charAt(i);
            if(caracter=='0'){
                numeroNot=numeroNot+'1';
            }
            else
                numeroNot=numeroNot+'0';

        }  
        System.out.println("NOT(" + num + ") = " + numeroNot);     
        
    }
    
    public static boolean verificarBinario(String num){
        boolean devolver=true;
        if(num.length() != 8){
             System.out.println("El numero introducido no tiene 8 bits");
             devolver=false;
        }     
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
            char caracter = num.charAt(i);
            if(caracter!='0'&&caracter!='1'){                
                devolver=false;
                System.out.println("Ingresar sólo 1 o 0");
                break;
            } 
        }  
        return devolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: Comprendo, yo habia intentado hacer el cambio y dentro del cambio concatenar el siguiente caracter, no he caido que de hecho... es un bucle asi que se repite y puedo poner la condicion para que se repita... Gracias me sirve

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el operando binario not de esta forma:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String binString = "00010001"; // en decimal es el 17
    int intValue = Integer.parseInt(binString, 2);
    
    System.out.println("Valor binario: " + binString);
    System.out.println("Valor decimal: " + intValue);
    
    int intValueNot = ~intValue;
    String strValueNot = Integer.toBinaryString(intValueNot);
    
    strValueNot = strValueNot.substring(strValueNot.length() - 8);
    
    System.out.println("Valor binario negado: " + strValueNot);
    System.out.println("Valor decimal negado: " + intValueNot);

}
```

La salida es la siguiente:

```
Valor binario: 00010001
Valor decimal: 17
Valor binario negado: 11101110
Valor decimal negado: -18
```

Comment: Eso me valdría, pero el objetivo del ejercicio es hacerlo con bucles, perdon por no explicarlo en el enunciado. Ahora lo cambio para ponerlo bien

Pero ya que me has puesto esta solución, una pregunta:
Cual es el objetivo de la línea 
strValueNot = strValueNot.substring(strValueNot.length() - 8); ??

Soy nuevo en java y no entiendo del todo algunas funciones, un saludo

Comment: Es sólo para quedarme con el binario del mismo tamaño que el original, es decir 8 bits.

Answer (score 1):

La verdad esto se puede hacer muy sencillamente si conoces los operadores bitwise y conoces que [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) tiene métodos que te permiten leer un número en cierta base (binario, octal, decimal, hexadecimal como los más comunes).

Usaremos para este programa:

- [Scanner.hasNext(Pattern)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext(java.util.regex.Pattern))
- [Scanner.nextShort(radix)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextShort(int))
- Operador Bitwise NOT
- El Pattern `"[01]{8}$"` que nos indica que está buscando un patrón de 8 dígitos binarios (8 dígitos ceros y unos). Este Pattern se usará para evaluar si la entrada es correcta

El operador bitwise NOT como nos indica el [tutorial de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

> The unary bitwise complement operator "~" inverts a bit pattern; it can be applied to any of the integral types, making every "0" a "1" and every "1" a "0". For example, a byte contains 8 bits; applying this operator to a value whose bit pattern is "00000000" would change its pattern to "11111111".
>
> ---
>
> El operador de complemento bitwise unario "~" invierte un patrón de bits; se puede aplicar a cualquiera de los tipos integrales, haciendo que cada "0" sea un "1" y cada "1" un "0". Por ejemplo, un byte contiene 8 bits; aplicar este operador a un valor cuyo patrón de bits es "00000000" cambiaría su patrón a "11111111".

Esto con la lógica:

1. Si todos son 0, entonces el byte debe valer 0
2. Si todos son 1 y los negamos, el byte debe valer 0

## Código

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        byte num;

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("\nIntroduce un número binario de 8 bits: ");

            while (true) {
                if (scanner.hasNext("[01]{8}$")) {
                    num = (byte) scanner.nextShort(2);
                    break;
                }
                scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.print("\rIntroduce un número binario de 8 bits: ");
            }

            if (num == 0 || ~num == 0) {
                System.out.println("Lo has conseguido: " + num);
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("No todos los dígitos eran 0 o 1");
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

**Notas:**

1. Se usa `Scanner.nextShort(2)` y luego se castea a byte puesto que `Scanner.nextByte(2)` lee los números como positivos, para indicar que sea negativo se tendría que colocar el signo menos (e.j. `-00000001`) recordando que `11111111` en byte es negativo
2. Si no se quiere usar el bitwise NOT, podría cambiarse el if a `if(num == 0 || num == -1)`